# You have already authorized yourapp

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I have integrated social auth android.jar with my app. When I open the Facebook activity, it takes me to the login screen and after it displays "You have already authorized your app",
with Cancel and Ok buttons. When I press any of the buttons, it is giving me the error  "Verification code is null".

Log is as follows:

```
04-17 08:24:35.266: I/Choreographer(892): Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-17 08:24:36.005: I/Choreographer(892): Skipped 73 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-17 08:24:37.226: D/SocialAuth-WebView(892): Override url: fbconnect://success#access_token=BAACCZB9kzh04BAInZAmZCqfeFKRMj6hgee0SPfF88iISLsLm0LST0VedaN4CiHVvJU7ZAZAr37XseCfy2cZBZBpTOvqcLNgIINV1cNdaQ5W2FYEtSvZCtZBpiQaT9fKTY7U7QPNLlotRJallfpvgKZAH5CYcZAHESWAM0SOnCCbIwsSqF8YM4NmiF8dL7osVZCUJy0JNw8HDXZCre6wZDZD&expires_in=5182406
04-17 08:24:37.306: I/SocialAuthManager(892): Connecting provider : facebook
04-17 08:24:37.306: I/FacebookImpl(892): Retrieving Access Token in verify response function
04-17 08:24:37.348: I/OAuth2(892): Verifying the authentication response from provider
04-17 08:24:37.348: W/System.err(892):  org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: Verification code is null
04-17 08:24:37.348: W/System.err(892):  at org.brickred.socialauth.oauthstrategy.OAuth2.verifyResponse(OAuth2.java:114)
04-17 08:24:37.348: W/System.err(892):  at org.brickred.socialauth.oauthstrategy.OAuth2.verifyResponse(OAuth2.java:102)
04-17 08:24:37.348: W/System.err(892):  at org.brickred.socialauth.provider.FacebookImpl.doVerifyResponse(FacebookImpl.java:164)
04-17 08:24:37.375: W/System.err(892):  at org.brickred.socialauth.provider.FacebookImpl.verifyResponse(FacebookImpl.java:154)
04-17 08:24:37.375: W/System.err(892):  at org.brickred.socialauth.SocialAuthManager.connect(SocialAuthManager.java:183)
04-17 08:24:37.375: W/System.err(892):  at org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthDialog$SocialAuthWebViewClient$1.run(SocialAuthDialog.java:266)
04-17 08:24:37.375: W/System.err(892):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-17 08:24:37.375: D/SocialAuthError(892): org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: Verification code is null
04-17 08:24:37.375: D/Facebook(892): Authentication Error
04-17 08:24:37.410: I/Choreographer(892): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-17 08:24:38.165: I/Choreographer(892): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Why don't you show us some code? We're not telepathic you know...

Answer (score 3):

**http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/issues/detail?id=52**

This has been solved. Facebook did some changes in their login mechanism, that is why this occurred (according to the social auth people).

Comment: me also facing the same login and after that displaying that this app is already authorized.