# SocialAuthException: verification code is null

Tags: vaadin, socialauth

I'm trying to authorize using `socialauth` and `facebook apps`.

I've created an application there, got `App ID` and `App Secret`. Then I set `website` with `site URL : http://localhost:8080/pmc-web/`.

In my application in the last line I've got `SocialAuthException`. Why?

```
SocialAuthConfig config = SocialAuthConfig.getDefault();
config.load();
SocialAuthManager manager = new SocialAuthManager();
manager.setSocialAuthConfig(config);  
String successUrl = "http://localhost:8080/pmc-web";
String url = manager.getAuthenticationUrl("facebook", successUrl);
VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession().setAttribute("authManager", manager);
manager = (SocialAuthManager)VaadinService.getCurrentRequest().getWrappedSession().getAttribute("authManager");
AuthProvider provider = manager.connect(SocialAuthUtil.getRequestParametersMap((HttpServletRequest) SocialAuthUtil.getRequestParametersMap((HttpServletRequest) VaadinService.getCurrentRequest()))); //SocialAuthException
```

Full stacktrace

```
org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: Verification code is null
        at org.brickred.socialauth.oauthstrategy.OAuth2.verifyResponse(OAuth2.java:136)
        at org.brickred.socialauth.oauthstrategy.OAuth2.verifyResponse(OAuth2.java:102)
        at org.brickred.socialauth.provider.FacebookImpl.doVerifyResponse(FacebookImpl.java:189)
        at org.brickred.socialauth.provider.FacebookImpl.verifyResponse(FacebookImpl.java:179)
        at org.brickred.socialauth.SocialAuthManager.connect(SocialAuthManager.java:184)
        at com.xxx.app.pmc.vaadin.component.security.form.LoginForm$1.buttonClick(LoginForm.java:84)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:508)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:198)
        at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:161)
        at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:979)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:393)
        at com.vaadin.ui.Button$1.click(Button.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:168)
        at com.vaadin.server.ServerRpcManager.applyInvocation(ServerRpcManager.java:118)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:287)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:180)
        at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:93)
        at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1406)
        at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:305)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java
:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.ja
va:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFil
ter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolde
rAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.
java:150)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthentic
ationProcessingFilter.java:199)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsync
ManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilt
er.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: please show the complete stack trace

Comment: I found several mentions of this problem, could be a version issue with your jars. See https://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/issues/detail?id=52 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15986651/socialauth-android-authorization-successfull-with-facebook-but-verification-code